# Cannot iterate through list with for loop in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

my program uses `findall` function from `re` library to sum all the numbers in a file:

```
fh=open(fname)
lst=re.findall('[0-9]+',fh.read())
```

`findall` supposedly returns a list right ? so i'm supposed to loop through it like this :

```
for i in lst :
 s=s+int(lst[i])
```

but i get traceback error that says :

```
    s=s+int(lst[i])
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

Now it works just fine if i use `range()` :

```
for i in range(len(lst))
```

I just don't understand why i get this error cause list is by default indexed with integers right ?
can someone explain to me ? thank you !

Comment: Welcome to SO! Check out the [tour]

Comment: for i in lst :
 s=s+int(i)... But the Best will be to put the cast in a try...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`for i in lst:` already takes out the elements one-by-one and you don't require to index the list. So try:

```
for i in lst :
    s=s+int(i)
```

---

As you are trying to get the elements out of the list, `for i in lst:` does that job. So for example:

```
lst = [1,2,3,4]
for i in lst:
    print(i)
```

gives the output:

```
1
2
3
4
```

Comment: thank you, i was being a dummy there with the list[i] thing, i get it now

Answer (score 3):

You have two ways to do it:

```
for i in range(len(lst)):
 s += int(lst[i])
```

and second:

```
for i in lst:
 s += int(i)
```

Comment: FWIW, the second way is the preferred style.

Comment: Why did you edit my answer? There was no mistake in it. You just inserted null characters.

Comment: @Joshua, See Fahad's comment above. Fahad, I agree, and you should revert it. It's bad English syntax to have a space before a colon.

Answer (score 1):

`i` is a string, so `lst[i]` fails.

You could convert it to an int with `lst[int(i)]`, but that's not really what you're trying to do. See [Joshua's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61175120/4518341) for how to fix it.